# Cocoaasyncsocket problem, GCDAsyncSocket Connection problem

Tags: swift, cocoaasyncsocket

why when trying to connect when the server does not respond "try" shows that it is connected?

I need to check the connection status. Every time, despite the timeout setting, it shows that it is connected ...

My code:

```
        socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
        do {
            try socket?.connect(toHost: "192.168.1.1", onPort: 5000, withTimeout: 5)
            print ("connect")

        }catch  {
            print("socket error")

        }
```

And
 one more question,

i create two socket on the same port:

```
socket1.connect(toHost: "192.168.1.1", onPort: 5000, withTimeout: 5)
socket2.connect(toHost: "192.168.1.1", onPort: 5000, withTimeout: 5)
```

in func:

```
func socketDidDisconnect(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, withError err: Error?) {
 ...
}
```

How to detect which socket (socket1 or socket2 ) has been disconnected?

Answer (score 0):

GCDAsyncSocket does have delegate methods (and in your code example above, you do set the delegate to `self`).  So implement a tiny function with the Swift equivalent of this function:

[`- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port`](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Reference_GCDAsyncSocket#socket_didConnectToHost_port)

Something like:

```
socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
do {
    // I don't think socket should be optional here...
    try socket.connect(toHost: "192.168.1.1", onPort: 5000, withTimeout: 5)

} catch  {
    print("socket error")

}

func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16)
{
    print("connected to \(host) & \(port)")
}
```

where you've moved your "`print("connected!")`" there.  If the socket connected, you'll see the print appear in your console.

Comment: What if it can't connect? how to check ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: if there's an error,  you should see the "`socket error`"  appear in your console.  That's what your `catch` case is for.

Comment: Well, the problem is that there is no error. I write with "connected" even though it is not connected.

Comment: so the `didConnectToHost` method does fire (if you set a breakpoint there, would it hit and stop Xcode execution?).  I just updated the "connected" line.  What host & port are connected?

Comment: If the server is running I have:
connected to 192.168.1.1 & 5000

If the server is not running I don't have any error ...

Comment: No. I still have a problem. Why doesn't an error appear when it can't connect? and how to check if I'm currently connected or disconnected ....

Answer (score 0):

I would assign a value to the "tag" property on each socket, and then, on the delegate, compare the socket.tag parameter to figure out which one disconnected.

```
socket1.tag = 1
socket2.tag = 2


func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16)
{
    if (socket.tag==1) {
       print("Socket 1 disconnected")
    } 
}
```

Comment: Value of type 'GCDAsyncSocket?' has no member 'tag'